# During click on the back button in the react hooks web app, it is not navigating to the Home page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

While navigating back in the react hooks web app, it is not displaying the Home page.Do I need to include anything else, could someone please advise here ? I couldn't see any errors in console.

CSB link added:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-sun-rhog82?file=/src/components/home.js

```
import Select from "react-select";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const options = [
  { value: "test1@test.com", label: "test1@test.com" },
  { value: "test2@test.com", label: "test2@test.com" },
  { value: "test3@test.com", label: "test3@test.com" }
];

const Register = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const moveBack = () => {
    navigate("home");
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Lets us Know</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="candiate" /> <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" /> <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <Select isMulti options={options} />
        <br></br>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <hr></hr>
        <button>Submit</button>
        <button onClick={moveBack}>Back</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/home";
import Register from "./components/register";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        {/* <Navigation /> */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/Register" element={<Register />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is:

```
const moveBack = () => {
    navigate("home");
  };
```

Change it to:

```
const moveBack = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };
```

You've specified your `</Home>` component's rendering route as the root of the directory:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
```

So nothing was going to render when you navigated to */Home*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. It worked. Will accept soon and upvote..

Comment: One question in between, if I have to fill something in Register component, while navigating back it is getting cleared. What i have to do to retain in the form content ?

Comment: You need to link the input data to component state and store it in the `</App>` component so it doesn't get lost from the `</Register>` component demounting.

Comment: Thank you, have you got an example to share ?

Comment: [Here is the link to the React documentation on the useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)